# CellIdentityGsm on android

Tags: android

In the code below, getCid(), getPsc(),getLac(),GetMnc(), getMcc() are all resulting in same vaules.

Tested on API 17, with permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES"/>
```

In java

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
List<CellInfo> cellinoflist= tm.getAllCellInfo();
for(CellInfo cellinfo : cellinoflist)
{
...
CellInfoGsm GSMinfo = (CellInfoGsm) cellinfo;
CellIdentityGsm gsmCellIdentity= GSMinfo.getCellIdentity();
if(gsmCellIdentity!= null) {
        Log.d(TAG, " mCid: "+gsmCellIdentity.getCid()+" mPsc: "+
             gsmCellIdentity.getPsc()+" mLac: "+gsmCellIdentity.getLac()+
     " mMnc: "+gsmCellIdentity.getMnc()+" mMcc:"+gsmCellIdentity.getMcc());
    }
 .....
}
```

Logcat

```
mCid: 2147483647 mPsc: 2147483647 mLac: 2147483647 mMnc: 2147483647 mMcc:2147483647
```

am I missing something here,please suggest me.

Comment: Where do you assign `cellinfo`?

Comment: updated missing code.

Answer (score 0):

It should be clear that "2147483647" is a maximum int value. Most likely the code has an issue and the value is a default max value, not just the same value.

First of all you should check:

```
if(cell instanceof CellIdentityGsm){...
```

before casting. Unless it was just left out.